# Remove From multidimensional array if a value is duplicate

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comparing elements in a multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030334/comparing-elements-in-a-multidimensional-array)

My array look like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [event_key] => 1
            [event_id] => 5
            [event_desc] => Test Event 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [event_key] => 2
            [event_id] => 2
            [event_desc] => Test Event 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [event_key] => 3
            [event_id] => 5
            [event_desc] => Test Event 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [event_key] => 4
            [event_id] => 4
            [event_desc] => Test Event 4

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [event_key] => 5
            [event_id] => 5
            [event_desc] => Test Event 5

        )

)
```

I want to remove a sub array if event_id is duplicate

So Desired result is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [event_key] => 1
            [event_id] => 5
            [event_desc] => Test Event 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [event_key] => 2
            [event_id] => 2
            [event_desc] => Test Event 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [event_key] => 4
            [event_id] => 4
            [event_desc] => Test Event 4

        )


)
```

Comment: Aah, there are so many effing duplicates of this! One line hint answer: `foreach ($array as $val) { $deDuplicated[$val['event_id']] = $val; }`. Voila!

Comment: its very simple but for that your PHP for handling array should be clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this shall do the trick:

```
$knownIds = array();
foreach( $myArray AS $key=>$item ) {
  if( array_key_exists($item['event_id'], $knownIds) === true ) {
    unset( $myArray[$key] );
  } else {
    $knownIds[$item['event_id']] = $key;  // value does not matter really here
  }
}
$myArray = array_values($myArray);
```

where `$myArray` is your source array.

Comment: but unset don't reset index of the array

Comment: True, it was just example of the approach. Edited

Comment: thanks array_values() did the rest of task ;)